# Create list upon feature installation in Sharepoint Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint feature that includes a settings list template, which is read by other features. The list must have a particular name for the whole thing to work, so ideally I would rather have a list created instead of a list template.

I tried playing with the `EventReceiver` class, by overriding `FeatureInstalled` method. It receives a parameter of `SPFeatureReceiverProperties` type. I've looked through documentation, and saw that one property, `UserCodeSite`, refers to the `SPSite` where the feature is installed, if it is a `Site` scoped solution, which it is in my case. That way I wanted to write a piece of code that would create a specific list from the list template included in the feature.

```
SPWeb_object.Lists.Add(listName, "", SPListTemplate_object)
```

However the property is null, as well as the `Feature` property. So I can't get the SPSite object, and I can't get the SPWeb object.

Any other ideas?

Comment: so, in your Sharepoint project are you having the List created upon implementation?

Comment: I want to have that. And it would be preferable to have that list created from a template. So far I only have the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new list instance ListInstance construct. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx
The list will be created upon activating that particular feature. For automatic activation of a feature you can use feature stapling. See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648422.aspx

Comment: I created the `<Field>`s, then the content type, then the list definition, and then I filled it with data. It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

List creation is a very common requirement.  It's often best to create a list instance upon activation rather than installation, as suggested by another poster.  You can access the desired activation scope (the SPWeb or SPSite in which the feature is activated) like so:

```
SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
```

or

```
SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the `properties.Feature` is null in my case. I am currently trying out a solution similar to what Vojtech Nadvornik proposed.

Comment: The properties.Feature member should not be null for a feature scoped to SPWeb, SPSite or SPWebApplication.  If it is then something may be wrong with the custom solution and/or the farm configuration.  It may be best to address the root cause regardless of how you choose to proceed.